# Вывести текст на картинку по вертикали

Tags: c#, winforms, текст

Каким образом можно перевернуть текст по вертикали?

Т.е сейчас он располагается по горизонтали

[image: Текст по горизонтали]

но для удобства и читабельности его нужно перевернуть:

[image: Текст по вертикали]

```
private Bitmap Merge(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2)
{
    var res = new Bitmap(bmp1.Width + bmp2.Width, Math.Max(bmp1.Height, bmp2.Height));

    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(res))
    {
        graphics.DrawImage(bmp1, Point.Empty);
        graphics.DrawImage(bmp2, new Point(bmp1.Width, 0));
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Если нужно именно _текст_ вывести, то смотрите [1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-draw-vertical-text-on-a-windows-form?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), [2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-vertical-text?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: После того как задал вопрос https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-vertical-text?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8 и начал читать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перед создаем общей картинки выполните поворот `bmp2` методом [RotateFlip](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.rotateflip?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0):

```
bmp2.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
var res = new Bitmap(bmp1.Width + bmp2.Width, Math.Max(bmp1.Height, bmp2.Height));
```

Comment: Огонь, Спасибо!